# Why is ajax call in window.unonload never called?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have an upload view written in Angularjs. I want to ensure that during an upload if the page is **reloaded** or **closed**; all files that uploaded to the server should be removed for consistency. So what I tried is as following:

```
// this function is under /upload view, and inside UploadController
window.onunload = function () {
   $http.delete(...call delete on my server..);
};
```

howevever, DELETE does not reach to server, what am I missing?

Comment: the `onunload` event probably fires, but it does not halt the browser in any way, it will still reload the page, so there's no guarantee that the ajax call will ever finish before the page is reloaded, which is why this is generally not done, it tends to fail.

Comment: but I am not waiting any results, just firing it as you see, no callbacks. any workarounds for that?

Comment: There's still no guarantee anything would  be sent. Did you place a console.log in the there to see if fires at all ?

Comment: Have you thought about adding a final ajax call on the completion event of your uploads? On the server, you can look for the completion callback to "persist" the files.

Comment: @anvarik You **are** waiting on results... you're making an HTTP call.  Just because your code doesn't care what the response is, the underlying call has to.  Even if it bails before the response, it could have also bailed out before the network connection was even established.

Comment: I see, so it seems no way to make this call synchronous, then how can I make this consistency check, any ideas?

Comment: @adeneo sometimes it fires, sometimes not, as you said since the call is not synchronous no guarantee at all

Comment: @B2K can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: There's never any guarantee when using `onunload`, `onbeforeunload` etc. as you can't stop the user from leaving your site, browsers will not allow that. It's quite common that sometimes the request goes through, other times it doesn't, it depends on how long time the browser uses to redirect etc.

Comment: I've not used angularjs, that's why I didn't post an answer. Anyway, $http will have a completion event that you can add a method call to. In that event, add another $http call which triggers a method on your server to remove the posted file names from your session. When the session expires, delete any files whose names are still in the session. Or post the files to a temporary location. Move them to a permanent location in the callback. Use a cron job to clean the temp directory of old files.

Comment: [`[javascript] onunload ajax`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+onunload+ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue before too. Open up the browser console and go to the network tab. Now navigate away from the page. You will see for a quick moment that your ajax request is marked as `(canceled)` because the browser cancels the request as you move away.

[image: Save failing]

I've observed this behaviour in google chrome and haven't checked other browsers, but if it doesn't work reliably in one of the most popular browsers then you know this isn't a reliable solution overall.

Basically, there is no reliable way to do this. I've found not even doing the ajax call in `window.onbeforeunload` is reliable.

If I were you, I would put an expiry date on your uploaded files and have a cron job that deletes them after the expiry date is reached. Even if `window.onunload` worked, it still wouldn't be a reliable solution—for example, when a user's machine unexpectedly shuts down.